# Want to Show Sub categories under Categories section using Woo Commerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce, design

Hi I'm working on an e commerce project in which I need to show the categories like this.

Category1
    Sub-Category1
    Sub-Category2
    Sub-Category3
Category2
Category3
    Sub-Category1
    Sub-Category2

How can I do this in Woo Commerce?